# Calling function from c# to JS File

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I am using an inline jquery in the c# code and it works. But when I try to call it through js file, it does not work.

C# code

```
tableCell.Attributes.Add("onclick", 
                         @" if($(""div[id*='Name'] input[id*='" +
                         checkboxID + @"']"").is(':checked')" );
```

Here, I get the value true. So Now I try to make a function in js file and call it.

```
tableCell.Attributes.Add("onclick",
                         "javascript:Foo(this,'" + checkBoxID + "');
                         return false;");
```

Js File :

```
function ToggleScorecardConfig(sender,checkboxID) {
    var a = checkboxID + "@";
    alert(a); //WORKS
    alert($(""div[id*='Name'] input[id*='" + checkBoxID +
              @"']"").is(':checked')); //ERROR : ')' Expected
}
```

I know I am doing some very small mistake, Can anyone please guide me.

Answer (score 1):

You have double double quotes in the JS file code, should just be:

```
$("div[id*='Name'] input[id*='" + checkBoxID + "']")
```

The '@' is used to escape the double quotes in C#, that's why the in-line code works, you don't need that in JS

Comment: It says '@' Invalid. double double quotes work in inline query.

Comment: This gives me false, but I should get true, as in Inline query, I get true value.

Comment: What do you get when  if you do

`alert($("div[id*='Name'] input[id*='" + checkBoxID + "']").length)`

Comment: In the inline query, I get some length as 2,4,11 but when I try with JS File, I get 0 only.

Comment: You checked that checkBoxID  has the right value? You can also debug the jQuery result and review the selector.